# How to use parameterized fixtures in parameterized tests?

Tags: python, pytest

I have some code that tests the values of a `Thing` object.

```py
import pytest


class Thing:
    def __init__(self, val) -> None:
        self.val = val
        print(f"Made a thing with val {val}", end=" ")


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def thing1():
    return Thing(1)


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def thing2():
    return Thing(2)


class TestThing:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "thing_name,expected_val",
        [
            ("thing1", 1),
            ("thing2", 2),
        ],
    )
    def test_thing_val(self, thing_name, expected_val, request):
        assert request.getfixturevalue(thing_name).val == expected_val

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "thing_name",
        [
            ("thing1"),
            ("thing2"),
        ],
    )
    def test_thing_useless(self, thing_name, request):
        assert request.getfixturevalue(thing_name)
```

Obviously all four tests pass. And as expected, the print statement only happens once per fixture as they get only created once due to being class-scoped.

However, I want to use `pytest.fixture`'s `params` keyword argument so that I don't have to declare multiple fixtures myself. How can I do this and get those fixtures, made by the `params` keyword argument, to be used in the tests, yielding the same results that my code currently does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with [pytest-lazy-fixture](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-lazy-fixture/). The tricky could be to get the test number.

Here is the code to achieve the same result:

```
import pytest

class Thing:
    def __init__(self, val) -> None:
        self.val = val
        print(f"Made a thing with val {val}", end=" ")

values = [1, 2]

@pytest.fixture(scope="class", params=values)
def thing(request):
    return Thing(request.param)

class TestThing:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "thing_instance,expected_val",
        [(pytest.lazy_fixture("thing"), [1, 2])],
    )
    def test_thing_val(self, thing_instance, expected_val, request):
        test_nr = int(request.node.name.split("[")[-1].split("]")[0][-1])
        assert thing_instance.val == expected_val[test_nr - 1]

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "thing_instance",
        [
            (pytest.lazy_fixture("thing")),
        ],
    )
    def test_thing_useless(self, thing_instance):
        assert thing_instance
```

Comment: I think I see what you are getting at, but this code does not work as-is. `In test_thing_val: function uses no fixture 'thing'`

Comment: What do you mean? I am pretty sure it should use them. If your confusion comes from no print message, remember that pytest capture it by default unless run with `pytest -s`

Comment: May not have been clear, sorry! The code you provided when run as-is throws an exception during test collection. It says `In test_thing_val: function uses no fixture 'thing'` and `ERROR myproject/tests/test_thing.py::TestThing` and `Interrupted: 1 error during collection`.

Comment: Strange, it works on my machine. What's your versions? I use `Python 3.10.6`, `pytest 7.1.3`, `pytest-lazy-fixture==0.6.3`

Comment: Yep, looks like this works on 3.10 and not 3.11. How odd. Thank you for the answer by the way; this is a clever solution.

Comment: With `Python 3.11.2` it passed as well :/

Comment: Double yep, looks like it works in a Docker container and not in my virtual environment made by Poetry. LOL! I scrapped my environment and remade it and now it works. No clue what happened there.

Comment: Probably we will never find it out, but glad it works now!